# Procedural parametric 3D modeling for sword blade shapes?

Tags: 3d, modeling, procedural-generation, procedural

I need to create several swords for a videogame and I was wondering if its possible to do it through procedural modeling.

So for example, based on the different blade shapes present in this picture

https://atkinson-swords.com/_Media/kurifil2_med.jpeg

I would like to be able to create , introducing some inputs, any or at least some of the shapes present in the ref image as a 3D object to be imported in unity or unreal.

Is it feasable? I'm learning 3D modeling myself right now so I'm quiet lost here.